# How to fetch phone numbers in ionic 5? Suggest plugins

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phone-number, ionic5

I need to show the popup to select the mobile number by the user like in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNPfp.jpg) .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here is my code: 
import { DeviceAccounts } from '@ionic-native/device-accounts/ngx';
this.deviceAccounts.get()
      .then(accounts1 => console.log('Acounts List =>'+JSON.stringify(accounts1)) )
      .catch(error => console.error(error)); 
 })  
While using this I got only an email accounts list. I need to get the mobile number list.